# Swing: make button disabled on click

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have a piece of code I'm working on, I prepared a simple example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Example extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example e = new Example();
        e.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JButton button;

    public Example() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(600, 400);
        this.setLayout(null);

        button = new JButton("button");
        button.setBounds(200, 150, 200, 50);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(button);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        button.setEnabled(false);
        
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The pooint is, we have `actionPerformed` function, that has two actions: disables the button and runs `sleep` to imitate some work that i do.

My problem is that button is being disabled after `actionPerformed` ends, so in other words after this 5 seconds of sleep, and I cannot disable it earlier. I've tried to do something with it but so far changing `button.setEnabled(false);` to `button.setEnabled(false); this.repaint(); this.validate();` does nothing.

My question is: how to do in swing the job, where I need first disable button, then do some time consuming stuff (sleep for example) and enable button when job is done?

Comment: I'm curious. Did you try [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswing%5D+thread+sleep) before you posted your question? Calling `Thread.sleep()` from _Swing_ code has been asked (and answered) quite a few times already. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498174/thread-sleep-in-actionperformed) looks very similar to yours. Do you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you cant `Thread.sleep()` on the same thread your UI is being created on or else it will freeze the UI until the *sleep* is finished.

What you would want to do is probably use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) or [Swing Worker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) instead.

Some other points:

1. Don't extend `JFrame` class unnecessarily
2. Don't use a null/`AbsoluteLayout` rather use an appropriate [LayoutManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
3. Don't call `setBounds()` or `setSize()`  on components, if you use a correct layout manager this will be handled for you
4. Call `JFrame#pack()` before setting the frame to visible
5. All Swing components should be called on the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`
6. I've also never been a fan of implementing the `ActionListener` on a class basis especially if you will have more than 1 component registering an `ActionListener`.

Here is an example of the changes made and using a `Timer`:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Example {

    private JButton button;
    private Timer timer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Example::new);
    }

    public Example() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

        button = new JButton("button");

        button.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
            if (timer != null && timer.isRunning()) {
                return;
            }
            
            button.setEnabled(false);

            timer = new Timer(5000, (ActionEvent e1) -> {
                // TODO do something after sleeping for 5 seconds
                button.setEnabled(true);
                timer.stop();
            });
            timer.start();
        });

        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@David Kroukamp Thanks a lot, that's what I was looking for. If anyone needed here is simple (but not perfect, see toDavid's answer) example with `Worker`

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Example extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example e = new Example();
        e.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JButton button;

    public Example() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(600, 400);
        this.setLayout(null);

        button = new JButton("button");
        button.setBounds(200, 150, 200, 50);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(button);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        button.setEnabled(false);
        startThread();
    }

    private void startThread() {

        SwingWorker sw1 = new SwingWorker() {
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                button.setEnabled(true);
            }
        };
        
        sw1.execute();
    }
}
```