# Java - How to impliment swing timer that clears a text field after 5 seconds?

Tags: java

I know im supposed to user a time, but am not sure how to implement it. I tried looking online, but I couldn't find anything relating to clearing a text field. Could someone show me how this is done.

Comment: I think, this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503788/confusion-with-the-java-swing-timer

Comment: When actionPerformed method is called, simply set the fields text to null our ""

Comment: Yea, but how do I impliment the time to work with that is what is confusing me :/

Comment: Have you taken a look at the link that Yegor Korotetskiy posted? That shows a good way to do it.